# How to split a DataTable in two separate by columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I have a DataTable which has many columns and only one row:

```
...
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
da.Fill(myDataSet);

myDataTable = new DataTable();
myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
...
```

How can I split the DataSet/DataTable to have equal amount of columns (if it is an odd number, split the columns so the first `DataTable` has the extra column).

Scenario #1:

Main `DataTable`:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8
9       0       9       5       7       4       9       3
```

`DataTable1`:

```
col1    col3    col3    col4
9       0       9       5
```

`DataTable2`:

```
col5    col6    col7    col8
7       4       9       3
```

Scenario #2:

Main `DataTable`:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7
9       0       9       5       7       4       9
```

`DataTable1`:

```
col1    col3    col3    col4
9       0       9       5
```

`DataTable2`:

```
col5    col6    col7
7       4       9
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you want to reach? It's possible (off course) to reach this, but I can think of no reason to do this...I'm quite sure that there is a better solution for your problem - whatever this is...

Comment: I have two separate repeater that I am trying to split the data between. The answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254126/how-to-generate-dynamic-labels-and-use-the-column-name-and-value-as-the-text works except I would like to split the datatable and use two separate to populate to two separate repeaters.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the whole data table and then remove the columns you don't want.

So for your first example, following code will return first four columns in datatable1 and remaining columns in datatable 2.

You can modify your code as per your number of columns

```
DataTable dataTable1;
dataTable1 = myDataTable.Copy();
dataTable1.Columns.RemoveAt(4);
dataTable1.Columns.RemoveAt(5);
dataTable1.Columns.RemoveAt(6);
dataTable1.Columns.RemoveAt(7);

DataTable dataTable2;
dataTable2 = myDataTable.Copy();
dataTable2.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
dataTable2.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
dataTable2.Columns.RemoveAt(2);
dataTable2.Columns.RemoveAt(3);
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not always the same amount of columns.

Comment: Yeah you need to modify it according to your column size

Comment: There is no dynamic way of doing it?

Comment: You can take column count in one variable, split it into 2 as per your 1st and 2nd example and use above code on these number of columns.

Comment: I updated my question with what you said but I am getting an error.

Comment: It is removing every other column for some reason.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: not surprised... you just need to keep `Remove(0)`-ing for `x` number of times, if you are looping (which I'm guessing you are)...

Answer (score 1):

You can as well use the overloaded version of [`DataView.ToTable(String, Boolean, String[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2b6ehaa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve this passing the required column names like below

```
DataView view1 = new DataView(myDataSet.Tables[0]);
DataTable table1 = view1.ToTable("Table1", true, "col1", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6");


DataView view2 = new DataView(myDataSet.Tables[0]);
DataTable table2 = view2.ToTable("Table2", true, "col2", "col7", "col8");
```